# How to determine whether Apache is using as Forward Proxy or Reverse Proxy?

Tags: apache, proxy, webserver, reverse-proxy

Apache can be used as **Forward Proxy** or **Reverse Proxy**, how to determine whether Apache is using as Forward Proxy or Reverse Proxy? I think it is configed in `httpd.conf` file, but I don't know which configuration field decide this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse  are the  directives that need to be configured to set up Apache as a reverse proxy.

In simple terms 'ProxyPass' performs unidirectional address space conversion from external to internal as in :

```
ProxyPass       /app1/  http://internal1.example.com/
ProxyPass       /app2/  http://internal2.example.com/
```

so `http://www.example.com/app1/some-path` maps to `http://internal1.example.com/some-path` as required.

while ProxyPassReverse  performs the inverse translation from the app/web -server response to the externally address space as in :

```
ProxyPassReverse /app1/ http://internal1.example.com/
ProxyPassReverse /app2/ http://internal2.example.com/
```

this enables self-references/references to other internal servers to not pass through as-is but to be converted to external address spaces,  in case of re-directs for example:

```
    HTTP/1.1 302 Found  
    Location: http://internal.example.com/foo/         
 //ProxyPass lets this through to user browser as-is!
```

with Reverse Proxy this gets returned to the user's browser as

```
  HTTP/1.1 302 Found
  Location: http://www.example.com/foo/
```

using a ProxyPassReverse  directive.